# Lucene 3.6.0 - SnowballAnalyzer Stemmer Deprecated

Tags: lucene, stop-words

today I was trying to use the **SnowballAnalyzer** on Lucene Java API v3.6.0 but it seems Deprecated already. When I try to use the analyzer on my code, the code stop when it reach the analyzer. Actually I want to use PorterStemmer but it was not available on luce, so I decided to use this snowball, but this problem occured.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Plus, does anyone know how to **set the stop word file format**, cause when I put:

```
a
as
able
about
above
according
accordingly
across
actually
after
afterwards
.
.
.
```

In the *stopword.txt*, and call it, the program stop. Can anyone share with me how to format the *stopword.txt* file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

being deprecated cannot make your code stop running. You must have some other issue.

Your stopword.txt seems to have the right format.

Comment: ok I got it, I found out the right format, thanks for the reply anyways!